# Delete few nodes in XML file in WSO2 ESB

Tags: xml, xslt, wso2, wso2-esb

I get an XML result from an endpoint in ESB. I have to store this result XML and also send this to an API to validate the contents. The validate API returns few items which are invalid and I have to delete those invalid items from XML and again send the XML to another Endpoint.

My Approach: 
Right now I am calling the endpoint API which returns XML records. I am storing it an Enrich Mediator as REQUEST_PAYLOAD. And also sending the same to Another Endpoint to validate. I have stored the result from the validate endpoint in a property again.  Then When I access the Request payload by $ctx:REQUEST_PAYLOAD I am getting the XML file. But I am not able to pass this XML to a XSLT where I have to delete few items based on the result of 2nd endpoint.

I should be able to pass this XML and also the result from validate API to the XSLT so that few items can be deleted from the XML and send to another API.

```
 Example: 
   1st XMl
  '<Data>  
     <User Name="XYZ">
     <DETAILS>
     <COURSE>IS</COURSE>
     <YEAR>2016</YEAR>
     <SUBJECT>COMPUTER SCIENCE<SUBJECT>         
    </DETAILS>
  </User>
 <User Name="ABC">
  <DETAILS>
   <COURSE>IS</COURSE>
    <YEAR>2015</YEAR>
    <SUBJECT>INFO SCIENCE<SUBJECT>         
   </DETAILS>
  </User>
 </Data>'

       2nd XML :
  '<message> ABC user is invalid </message>
     <value>ABC</value>'

    Result XML :
        Remove ABC from the 1st XML
    '<Data>  
    <User Name="XYZ">
    <DETAILS>
    <COURSE>IS</COURSE>
    <YEAR>2016</YEAR>
    <SUBJECT>COMPUTER SCIENCE<SUBJECT>         
   </DETAILS>
   </User>
  </Data> '
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. You expect a computer to understand `<message> ABC user is invalid </message>` as an instruction to delete `<User Name="ABC">` and its descendants?! I wouldn't understand it myself if I hadn't seen your expected result. -- Note also that your 2nd XML is not well-formed.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 properties type="OM" : REQUEST_PAYLOAD and say that the result from you validation API is saved in VALIDATION_PAYLOAD

Use enrich mediator to set REQUEST_PAYLOAD has the current message. For exemple, if your property contains the soap Body :

```
<enrich>
    <source type="property" property="REQUEST_PAYLOAD"/>
    <target type="body"/>
</enrich>
```

Use enrich mediator to append the content of VALIDATION_PAYLOAD in the current message, for exemple :

```
<enrich>
  <source clone="true" xpath="get-property('VALIDATION_PAYLOAD')"/>
  <target type="body" action="child"/>
</enrich>
```

Use log level="full" to see exactly what you get and then use xslt mediator

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest the following: after you receive the response from the validate endpoint you should save it to another property as validateResponse.  Next you should use Enrich or PayloadFactory to replace your $body with REQUEST_PAYLOAD.  Then you can call the XSLT mediator, which will replace your $body with its response.  You now have three payloads to play with as you choose.